# Is it possible to use another thread inside a lock to redirect output in a file?

Tags: c#, locking

I have two functions using a lock statement, where after some operations finished, I redirect the output in a .txt file. I have realised that their executions take a lot of time, resulting in blocking their operations and degrading the app's performance in general.

I was thinking that the high execution time could be due to the write operations into a file. What would be the most efficient way to reduce the execution time? Should I use another thread for the write operations, is it possible inside a lock without holding the lock?

A simplified version of my code is illustrated below:

```
    StatsInformation statsInfo = new StatsInformation ();
    List<int> lInt = new List<int>();

    public void FunctionEnq(List<byte> lByte, int _int)
    {
        lock (OperationLock)
        {
           //Do some work here 
           lInt.Add(_int);
           string result = "New Int " + _int + " size " + lInt.Count + " time " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff");
           statsInfo.WriteStatsInFile(result); 
        }
    }

    public (List<byte> _outByte, int _time) FunctionDeq()
    {
        List<byte> _outByte = new List<byte> ();
        int _time = -1;
        lock (OperationLock)
        {
           //Do some work here 
           _outByte.Add(...);
           int _int =  lInt[0];
           //do operations
           _time = _int;
           lInt.RemoveAt(0);
           string result = "Get Int " + _int + " new size " + lInt.Count + " time " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff");
           statsInfo.WriteStatsInFile(result); 
        }
        return (_outByte, _time);
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware of [System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: ... and logging Frameworks ( Serilog, log4net, NLog ... )?

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the information. I was aware about the Concurrent Namespace, but I preferred to use a list due to some operations and thought that sorting etc. a ConcurrentQueue would worsen the performance. Maybe I need to reconsider and check it again. As for the logging frameworks, I was not aware for the ones you mentioned (apart NLog, but never used it).

Comment: A logging framework, that's capable of async writing would be worth a try to circumvent the File I/O penalty. The other option would be to have a BlockingQueue in which you write the LogMessages, then have another thread consume it and do the File I/O.

Comment: Another thing here is that your protected blocks are pretty long. I'd try and make 'em shorter. That alone should improve performance.